# Como retornar o resultado de uma def?

Tags: python

Como posso pegar o resultado e mostrar no print fora do def?
Tentei de todas as formas, porém sempre me mostra "None", e quando coloco um print dentro da função me mostra apenas a primeira letra do texto.

```
def algo():
    x = "alguma coisa!"
    for i in x:
        return (i)

print(algo())
```

Comment: Rodando seu código funcionou para mim, retornou a primeira letra, que é o que seu código faz. Se colocar um print antes do `return`, ele vai mostrar apenas a primeira letra pois o return diz: "Saia da função e retorne esse valor onde ela foi chamada". Seria legal se você explicasse o que quer fazer, quais resultados quer pegar.

Answer (score -2):

Tente dessa forma:

```
def algo():
    x = "alguma coisa!"
    for i in x:
        print(i)

algo()
```

O `return` encerra a execução da função